# Volume Mounts for main directories of containers like /mnt, /dev, /var to volumes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

Can we mount directly the main dirs of containers to volumes as part of kubernetes podspec.
For ex:

- /mnt
- /dev
- /var

All files and subdir of /mnt, /dev, /var should be mounted to volumes as part of podspec.

How can we do this?

Comment: That sounds like you want to arrange with your sysadmins to run your processes directly on the nodes outside containers.  Access to any of these directories could have a significant impact on the operation of other containers and the node on the whole (and especially `/dev`) and I'd expect it to generally be restricted.

Comment: I tried 2 ways with PVC and without PVC, both are not working.

Comment: ```containers:
    image: test_container:latest
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    name: test-container
    resources: {}
    securityContext:
      privileged: true
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /mnt
      name: testvolume
    - mountPath: "/dev"
      name: devdata
  volumes:
    name: testvolume
```

Comment: Also not able to mount the container dirs /mnt in kubernetes podspec

Comment: it won't work with PVCs, you should be able to do this with hostPath

Comment: we are not trying to mount the filesystem of container to local system, the file system container should be mounted to volumes of local system. Below is the docker run command:  docker run -d --name test_container --volume test_volume:/mnt --privileged -v /dev:/dev test_container.

Comment: Looking for equivalent podspec for above docker command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For development purposes, you can create a [hostPath Persistent Volume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath), but if you want to implement this for production, I strongly recommend you to use some [NFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System).

Here you have an example on how to use a NFS in a Pod definition:

```
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: nfs-in-a-pod
spec:
  containers:
    - name: app
      image: alpine
      volumeMounts:
        - name: nfs-volume
          mountPath: /var/nfs # change the destination you like the share to be mounted to
  volumes:
    - name: nfs-volume
      nfs:
        server: nfs.example.com # change this to your NFS server
        path: /share1 # change this to the relevant share
```

And here an example of a `hostPath` Persistent Volume:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: task-pv-volume
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/data"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: task-pv-claim
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 3Gi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: task-pv-pod
spec:
  volumes:
    - name: task-pv-storage
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: task-pv-claim
  containers:
    - name: task-pv-container
      image: nginx
      ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: "http-server"
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: "/usr/share/nginx/html"
          name: task-pv-storage
```

In the `hostPath` example, all files inside /mnt/data will be mounted as /usr/share/nginx/html in the Pod.